Unable to access the registration page in ASP.NETCore
Account folder in project and Register.cs modelProgram.cs codeThis is the user registration controller code on the site that returns the registration view, but when it runs and clicks on the registration, I get a 404 error. Even the registration page follows _Layout.
 public class AccountController : Controller
 {
    
     //Dependency Injection
     private readonly checkRegisterUser _checkRegisterUser;

     public AccountController(checkRegisterUser checkRegisterUser)
     {
         checkRegisterUser = _checkRegisterUser;
     }
     
   

     [HttpPost]
     public IActionResult Register(UA_ViewModel register)
     {
         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             return View("Register", register);
         }

         if(_checkRegisterUser.isExistUserEmail(register.userEmail.ToLower()))
         {
             ModelState.AddModelError(key:"userEmail", errorMessage:"این ایمیل قبلا ثبت شده است");
             return View("Register", register);
         }
          UsersAccounts user = new UsersAccounts()
         {
             userName = register.userName,
             userEmail = register.userEmail,
             userPassword = register.userPassword
         };
         _checkRegisterUser.addUser(user);
         return View("Register", register);
     }
}

I tried to solve the error by giving [Route()] attribute and writing Constructor but no change was made.

Hi @AliHANiF, 1. How do you configure the route template in Program.cs? 2. How is your razor view code and pls F12 in the browser to check your request url? Are you sure you send the post request with correct url? Besides, do you use Area for the controller and views?

have you tried putting [AllowAnonymous] on the action method ?

I used the AllowAnonymous feature for the registration extension and I get a 405 error

Hi Rena, In Program.cs Map Controller Route is located on the Home controller by default and this user registration code is located on the Account Controller.

Hi @AliHANiF, 1. can you share the screenshot for the location of the AccountController? 2. could you pls share your Program.cs? 3. also pls F12 in the browser and choose the Network panel to check the request you send. Pls share enough code, it would be more helpful to resolve your issue. If not mind, you can also create a minimal repo to share with us.

Hi Rena, nice to see your comment again. Above, I put the program.cs image, as well as the account folder and its models, which are different from the Home controller.

By default, the site uses the Home controller. The registration model is connected to a table in the database via an email and the username validation model, but I couldn't find a logical reason for the 404 registration view error. In my opinion, it is a logical fallacy.

For the user registration controller, you must create a get type action and a post controller to send the form information. In the view, the action field in the form tag must point to the post controller .
in cotroller  :
 public class AccountController : Controller
 {
    
     //Dependency Injection
     private readonly checkRegisterUser _checkRegisterUser;

     public AccountController(checkRegisterUser checkRegisterUser)
     {
         checkRegisterUser = _checkRegisterUser;
     }

     [httpGet("[action]")]
     publick IActionResult Register()
     {
        View();
     }

     [HttpPost("[action]")]
     public IActionResult Register(UA_ViewModel register)
     {
         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             return View(register);
         }

         if(_checkRegisterUser.isExistUserEmail(register.userEmail.ToLower()))
         {
             ModelState.AddModelError(key:"userEmail", errorMessage:"این ایمیل قبلا ثبت شده است");
             return View(register);
         }
          UsersAccounts user = new UsersAccounts()
         {
             userName = register.userName,
             userEmail = register.userEmail,
             userPassword = register.userPassword
         };
         _checkRegisterUser.addUser(user);
         return View(register);
     }
}

and in view :
<form action="/Account/Register" type="post">
...
</form>


This is the view interface, but you use the [HttpPost] attribute identifier, if the post data submission, please do not use return view(...) ;
